# When you double-click on the widget is thrown

Tags: extjs, widget, extjs6, focusable

## When I do double-click on the widget is thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focusable' of undefined

I have grid with widget column

```
text:'blabala'
flex: 1.8,
xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
dataIndex: 'attachment',
stopSelection: false,

widget: {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'hbox',
            padding: 5,
            border: 0,
            bodyStyle: 'background:transparent',
            flex: 1,
            header: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                flex: 1,
                bodyStyle: 'background:#d7d7d7;border-radius:16px',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [

                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        cls: 'attach-btn-divers',
                        padding: '10 0 10 5',
                        textAlign: 'left',
                        flex: 1,
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        cls: 'attach-btn-divers attach-btn-divers-cancel',
                        padding: '10 5 10 0',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-close',
                        handler: 'onDetachDiver',
                        width: 20,
                    },
                ]
            }, {
                xtype: 'combolabel',
                forceSelection: true,
                store: {
                    type: 'divingAttachmentStore'
                },
                displayField: 'value',
                valueField: 'value',
                autoSelect: true,
                queryCaching: false,
                queryMode: 'remote',

                listConfig: {
                    loadMask: false
                },
                flex: 1,
                listeners: {
                    specialkey: 'onEditAttachment',
                    focusLeave: 'onFocusLeaveAttachment',
                    beforequery: 'onBeforeQueryAttachment'
                }
            },
            ]

        },
        onWidgetAttach: 'onWidgetAttachAttachment',
```

When editing, combos are displayed

In the normal view, a panel with buttons is displayed

if empty cell, then combos are displayed with empty text. When you click on the combo, a list drops but with an error

## Update 29.03.2017

If the edit plugin is removed, then there is no error.
Reproduced:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t1v

Comment: What is `combolabel`. Could'nt find anything in Doc.

Comment: combolabel is extended combo. If we replace combolabel on combo, the problem remains all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. I defined an empty editor to the widgetcolumn

```
 editor:{},
```

and the problem disappeared.